Different results from a script when using absolute or relative path in Linux
I get different behaviors running “/etc/init.d/wls start” compared to changing to the /etc/init.d directory and running “./wls start” on a RHEL 8 Linux system.  The first one uses “systemctl” while the second one uses the actual /etc/init.d/wls script, which calls the WLST scripting tool.
$ sudo /etc/init.d/wls start
Starting wls (via **systemctl**):

Compared to…
$ sudo ./wls start
Initializing **WebLogic Scripting Tool** (WLST) ...
Welcome to WebLogic Server Administration Scripting Shell
Type help() for help on available commands

Not quite sure why…. Thoughts???
When I look at the systemctl status for wls I see:
$ sudo systemctl status wls
● wls.service - SYSV: Oracle Weblogic NodeManager service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/wls; bad; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Tue 2024-03-26 14:16:24 MST; 2 weeks 2 days ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 12560 ExecStop=/etc/rc.d/init.d/wls stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 11522 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/wls start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Mar 26 14:16:22  wls[12560]: Connecting to Node Manager ...
Mar 26 14:16:22  wls[12560]: Successfully Connected to Node Manager.
Mar 26 14:16:22  wls[12560]: Killing server P6 ...
Mar 26 14:16:23  wls[12560]: Successfully killed server P6
Mar 26 14:16:23  wls[12560]: Killing server P6IntegrationAPI ...
Mar 26 14:16:23  wls[12560]: Successfully killed server P6IntegrationAPI
Mar 26 14:16:23  wls[12560]: Killing server AdminServer ...
Mar 26 14:16:24  wls[12560]: Successfully killed server AdminServer
Mar 26 14:16:24  wls[12560]: Stopped Node Manager Process successfully
Mar 26 14:16:24  systemd[1]: Stopped SYSV: Oracle Weblogic NodeManager service.

BUT I do not see the wls.service under /usr/lib/systemd/system.
I can disable the wls service with the "ystemctl disable wls" command.  But simply curious why this action is occurring.
